# Does @property copy in combination with readonly make sense?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

If I understand this correctly, `copy` enforces the setter to create a copy of the object passed in. However, if I use it together with `readonly`, there won't be a setter. So is my assumption correct, that combining `@property (copy, readonly)` doesn't make any sense or am I missing something?

Comment: Good question, I'm wondering if the `readonly` tag only makes the setter a private method, so it would still perform a copy when you set it within the class itself?  ie `self.myProperty = newThing;`

Comment: Apple's doc has this though: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW19

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It does make sense. For instance, if you want to access a property's setter in your implementation only:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSData *data;

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data;

@end
```

and in the class continuation in the `.m` file:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSData *data;
@end
```

Note that the `copy, readonly` declaration in the public header is required in this case!

Comment: Same considerations apply if a subclass wants to redeclare a `readonly` property defined in the superclass as `readwrite` in its own implementation.

Comment: This is a rather rare special case in my experience, yet you are totally right (both of you), in this very special case one needs `copy` even for a read-only property.

Comment: I'm not sure since when, but in Xcode 10+, you don't need to put `copy` in the `readonly` declaration even if you redeclare it as `readwrite` and `copy` in extension or subclasses. So the answer should be "No, it doesn't make sense."

Answer (score 16):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2) (which I've linked here for you):

> `copy`
>   Specifies that a copy of the object should be used for assignment.
>
> The previous value is sent a `release` message.
>
> The copy is made by invoking the `copy` method. This attribute is valid 
>   only for object types, which must implement the `NSCopying` protocol.

So yes, you're correct... `readonly` creates a getter method and `copy` would be effectively ignored, since there's no setter method that does assignment.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... as it actually _answers_ the question, lol.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, it does not make sense to have both.

Answer (score -2):

I think, if I saw such a property, on read, I would expect to receive a distinct returned object to the ivar unless the returned object was advertised to be immutable.

If I have

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSMutableArray* foo;
```

and I do this:

```
NSMutableArray* myFoo = [theObject foo];
[myFoo addObject: @"string"];
NSMutableArray* myOtherFoo = [theObject foo];
```

I would expect `myOtherFoo` not to have the extra string in it that `myFoo` has.

<s>Note: I haven't verified this yet.</s>

I have checked it now and my expectation is incorrect.  I think I would regard that as a bug.

Comment: The "copy" annotation means copy-on-set, not copy-on-get.

Comment: @HotLicks err, yes, I know.  Did you not read the last two lines of my answer?  Personally, I still regard it as a bug.

Comment: Why would you expect to modify the object and not have the change visible?  Two accesses of property "foo" will both fetch references to the same object.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean by "the object"? Do you mean the object returned by the property or the object that has the property?  If you mean the former, I would like successive invocations to return different instances (because the property says **copy**) for mutable objects.  If you mean the latter, modifying objects returned by properties with the current semantics is very bad because it breaks encapsulation - you are changing the internal state of the object without it knowing.

Comment: Like I said, the  "copy" annotation means copy-on-set, not copy-on-get.  If you want the object to be immutable make it immutable.  The above property specifically asks for "mutable".