# Does an Objective-C readonly property need to specify strong or copy?

Tags: objective-c, declared-property

If I have a read-only string property, is it necessary to specify `strong` (or `retain`) or `copy` in the declaration? If I don't specify, is one of them assumed?

It seems to me the ownership attribute is only useful when you have a setter.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *name;
```

Comment: "assign" is always assumed if not specify

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397322/does-property-copy-in-combination-with-readonly-make-sense for a similar discussion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is mostly correct. For a `readonly` property, `strong`, `retain`, `weak`, and `assign` have no effect. But if you also declare the property elsewhere as `readwrite` (most frequently in an anonymous category in the `.m`), then the other modifiers need to match.

Comment: Good answer! But if the readonly property doesn't have a getter and is not redeclared as readwrite internally, strong should apply to the property too because it has an ivar now, is this correct?