# Trouble with NSString and copy attribute

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning Objective C with the book "Programming with Objective C", but I'm stuck with the exercises 3 on page 66.

I have the following properties:

```
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *lastName;
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *firstName;
```

the following methods:

```
+ (id) personWithLastName:(NSString *)aLastName andFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName {
    return [[self alloc] initWithLastName:aLastName andFirstName:aFirstName;
}

- (id) initWithLastName:(NSString *)aLastName andFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _lastName = aLastName;
        _firstName = aFirstName;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) sayHello {
    NSString *greeting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@ %@!", [self firstName], [self lastName]];
    [self saySomething:greeting];
}
```

and the following code in the main:

```
NSMutableString *firstName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Steve"];
NSString *lastName = @"Jobs";

XYZPerson* firstPerson = [XYZPerson personWithLastName:lastName andFirstName:firstName];
[firstPerson sayHello];
```

which correctly print "Hello, Steve Jobs!".

Later, I added the following lines:

```
[firstName setString:@"John"];
[firstPerson sayHello];
```

which edit the property firstName in the object firstPerson, and print "Hello, John Jobs!".
However, firstName have the copy attribute, so why this happen?

Comment: I edited the post in order to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let's break this down...

This property says that we want only an accessor to be generated (the `readonly` part) plus we take ownership of the object via `copy` upon assignment (which in this case is never gonna happen because of the `readonly`)

```
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *lastName;
```

So a better form would be (unless you're interested in redeclaration of the property as `readwrite` in a class extension, [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397322/does-property-copy-in-combination-with-readonly-make-sense)):

```
@property (readonly) NSString *lastName;
```

and now we copy inside our `init` method before assignment to the backing ivars:

```
- (id) initWithLastName:(NSString *)aLastName andFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _lastName = [aLastName copy];
        _firstName = [aFirstName copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and of course the same applies to your other property also.

Comment: I think he might still want the copy in the declaration, just to make it explicit what's going to happen to the variables he passes into his init method.

Comment: @BenPious Yes that is why I've linked the other answer also. In that case he would have to redeclare the property as `readwrite` in his implementation file (if he intends to use the generated setter of course)

Comment: I saw that answer earlier. I'm just saying, if you declare it in the header as just readonly, and then copy it, that might create a problem if someone expects just an assignment to happen, but a copy happens instead. So it seems to me that while you have a choice about whether to do a readwrite getter in your implementation per that answer or just access the ivar directly like in yours, you shouldn't say that it's just readonly in the header when it's really being copied.

Comment: So, if I understand well, there are two possible solutions to the problem:
 (a) use the readonly attribute and make an explicit copy in the initialization, as in the answer;
 (b) use the copy attribute and use the setter in the initialization, like this: `[self setLastName:aLastName]; [self setFirstName:aFirstName]; ... `
 Is it right?

Comment: @Andrea Yep, that is correct. Although technically nothing would prevent you from declaring the property as readonly & copy if you wish as Ben suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The firstName and Lastname you are using in your main method are not the properties you declared, but instead new instance variables. To access the properties you want you can use _firstName to use the ivar or self.firstName to use the property's setter and getter methods.

EDIT: Disregard the above. Because you are using the ivar directly instead of calling the accessor method, the copy is not being made -- you have to call copy yourself.

Comment: But in the main method I invoked personWithLastName:andFirstName:, and so assigned the firstName and lastName (the ones declared in the main method) to the properties declared in the XYZPerson class.
Or not?