# Correct pattern for mutable vs immutable

Tags: objective-c, immutability, nscopying, mutability

I'm wondering what the correct pattern for implementing Mutable vs Immutable data structures would be. I understand the concept and how it works, but how should I implement if using an underlying Cocoa data structure? I mean, if I use a `NSSet`, for instance. Lets say I have the following:

```
// MyDataStructure.h
@interface MyDataStructure : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSSet * mySet;
@end


// MyDataStructure.m
@interface MyDataStructure ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet * myMutableSet;
@end

@implementation MyDataStructure

- (NSSet *)mySet
{
    return [_myMutableSet copy];
}

@end
```

The only reason I'm using a mutable set as the underlying data structure,is so that the mutable version of this class can tamper with it. `MyDataStructure` per se does not really need a mutable set. Therefore, assuming that I have implemented some initialisers to make this class useful, here's how `MyMutableDataStructure` looks like:

```
// MyDataStructure.h (same .h as before)
@interface MyMutableDataStructure : MyDataStructure

- (void)addObject:(id)object;

@end

// MyDataStructure.m (same .m as before)
@implementation MyMutableDataStructure

- (void)addObject:(id)object
{
    [self.myMutableSet addObject:object];
}

@end
```

By using this pattern the underlying data structure is always mutable, and its immutable version is just an immutable copy (or is it??).

This also begs another question that arises when implementing the `NSCopying` protocol. Here's a sample implementation:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    MyDataStructure * copy = [MyDataStructure allocWithZone:zone];
    copy->_myMutableSet = [_myMutableSet copyWithZone:zone];

    return copy;
}
```

Doesn't `copyWithZone:` return an immutable copy if that applies? So I'm basically assigning a `NSSet` instead to a `NSMutableSet` property, isn't that right?

Edit: While diving deeper into the issue I found some more issues surrounding this concern.

1. `mySet` should be `copy` instead of `strong`.
2. My `copyWithZone:` implementation isn't right either. I didn't mention it in the first post but that implementation relates to the Immutable version of the data structure (`MyDataStructure`). As I've read, Immutable data structures don't actually create a copy, they just return themselves. That makes sense.
3. Because of 2., I needed to override `copyWithZone:` in the Mutable version (`MyMutableDataStructure`).

To make things clear:

```
// MyDataStructure.h
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSSet * mySet;
```

And

```
// MyDataStructure.m
@implementation MyDataStructure

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    // We don't really need a copy, it's Immutable
    return self;
}

- (id)mutableCopyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    // I also implement -mutableCopyWithZone:, in which case an actual (mutable) copy is returned
    MyDataStructure * copy = [MyMutableDataStructure allocWithZone:zone];
    copy-> _myMutableSet = [_myMutableSet mutableCopyWithZone:zone];

    return copy;
}

@end

@implementation MyMutableDataStructure

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self mutableCopyWithZone:zone];
}

@end
```

It seems tricky at first, but I think I'm getting the hang of it. So the remaining questions are:

1. Is the pattern correct?
2. Does the getter for `mySet` return a mutable or immutable instance?
3. (not listed before) Do I really need the `copy` signal when using the `copy` property attribute?

I appreciate your patience to read this far.
Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apple is the way**

All across Apple's libraries the pattern that is used is, the mutable version of the class can be created through `-mutableCopy`, or (let's say the class is called `NSSomething`), then it can be created through the methods `-initWithSomething:(NSSomething*)something` or `+somethingWithSomething:(NSSomething*)something`.  `NSMutableSomething` always inherits from `NSSomething` and so the constructor methods are the same.  (i.e., `+[NSArray arrayWithArray:]` and `+[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]` return their respective instance types, also you pass in a mutable object to make an immutable copy, aka `[NSArray arrayWithArray:someNSMutableArrayObject]`)

So this is how I would do it:

**Interface**

MyDataStructure.h

```
// MyDataStructure.h
@interface MyDataStructure : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet * mySet;
+ (instancetype)dataStructureWithDataStructure:(MyDataStructure*)dataStructure;
- (instancetype)initWithDataStructure:(MyDataStructure*)dataStructure;
@end
```

MyMutableDataStructure.h

```
// MyMutableDataStructure.h
#import "MyDataStructure.h"
@interface MyMutableDataStructure : MyDataStructure
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet * mySet; // Only needs to redefine this property.  The instantiation methods will be borrowed from the immutable class.
@end;
```

**Implementation**

MyDataStructure.m

```
@implementation MyDataStructure

+ (instancetype)dataStructureWithDataStructure:(MyDataStructure *)dataStructure {
    return [[self alloc] initWithDataStructure:dataStructure];
}

- (instancetype)initWithDataStructure:(MyDataStructure *)dataStructure {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.mySet = [NSSet setWithSet:dataStructure.mySet];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)mutableCopy {
    return [MyMutableDataStructure dataStructureWithDataStructure:self];
}    

@end
```

MyMutableDataStructure.m

```
@implementation MyMutableDataStructure

- (instancetype)initWithDataStructure:(MyDataStructure *)dataStructure {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.mySet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:dataStructure.mySet];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

> By using this pattern the underlying data structure is always mutable, and its immutable version is just an immutable copy (or is it??).

No.  To cut down on memory footprint, immutable objects do not need the same overhead as their mutable counterparts.

**copyWithZone**

Just make sure you use `[self class]` so `MyMutableDataStructure` can inherit this method and return its own type, and also don't forget the call to `-init` after `+allocWithZone:`

`__typeof(self)` just declares the variable "`copy`" as whatever type `self` is, so it's completely inheritable by the mutable subclass.

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    __typeof(self) copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init]; // don't forget init!
    copy.mySet = [self.mySet copyWithZone:zone];
    return copy;
}
```

^ That method goes into the implementation of `MyDataStructure`

In your original implementation,

> // We don't really need a copy, it's Immutable

While this may be true for your project, it's an abuse of the naming convention.  A method that starts with `-copy` should return a copy of the object.

**Going a little off topic:**

I want to touch on some things I saw in your original question...The first is about hiding a "mutable object" with an "immutable object" pointer reference.  Maybe you need this functionality too, so here is a more robust way to do it and why.

MyClass.h (notice no ownership attributes - because it's only really an alias - aka we only need this for thy synthesis of setters and getters)

```
@property (nonatomic) NSSet *mySet;
```

MyClass.m

```
@interface MyClass () {
    NSMutableSet *_myMutableSet;
}
@implementation MyClass

// returns a copy of the internal mutable set as an NSSet
- (NSSet*)mySet {
    return [NSSet setWithSet:_myMutableSet];
}

// setter saves the internal mutable set as a copy of whatever set you hand it
- (NSSet*)setMySet:(NSSet*)mySet {
    _myMutableSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:mySet];
}
```

I defined `_myMutableSet` as an ivar, to protect the getters and setters further.  In your original code you put `@property (...) myMutableSet` in an interface extension in the .m file.  This synthesizes getters and setters automatically, so even if the declaration is apparently "private", one could call `[myDataStructure performSelector:@selector(setMutableSet:) withObject:someMutableSet];` and it will work despite the "Undeclared selector" compiler warning.

Also, in your original implementation of `-mySet`:

```
- (NSSet *)mySet {
    return [_myMutableSet copy];
}
```

This returns a copy of a pointer to `_myMutableSet`, type-casted as an `NSSet*`.  Therefore if someone re-casted it as `NSMutableSet*` they could alter the underlying mutable set.

Comment: When overriding `-copyWithZone:` you call the `-init` initializer and then copy the set. Could it be implemented as `[[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithDataStructure:self]`? It seems completely different as the set is not being allocated with the same zone, but does it make a difference?

Comment: The reason I'm saying this is because I used `NS_UNAVAILABLE` to inutilize the `-init` method...

Comment: Ok, so the copy/alloc with zone was a bit unclear to me, but I found this in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/initWithSet:copyItems:):  Basically when you call `-[NSSet initWithSet:]` it just copies the pointers.  If you want a deep copy use `...initWithSet:aSet copyItems:YES`; that calls `copyWithZone:` on each object.

Comment: So to answer that question, I think both would do the same thing (since `...allocWithZone:zone] initWithDataStructure:datastruct]` allocates a new `MyDataStructure`, and then that new data structure allocates its own `NSSet`, I assume it would be in the same zone, so I yes I think they are the same.

Comment: I'm totally astonished by following those docs. I found  this in `+ copyWithZone:`. `zone` `This argument is ignored.`. That changes things. I'm not sure I understand the whys and why nots of this, although from now on I'm assuming that it does indeed not make a difference to use `- initWithDataStructure:` when copying. If the zone argument is ignored it's irrelevant how you allocate, I think. No?

Comment: Ok, this explains it: `Do not override allocWithZone: to include any initialization code. Instead, class-specific versions of init... methods.
This method exists for historical reasons; memory zones are no longer used by Objective-C.`

Comment: Nice.  For anyone who's interested that's in the [NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/allocWithZone:)

Answer (score 0):

1. I cant tell if your pattern is correct, it depends.. If that approach is more comprehendable to you. then it is correct, but don't forget to add comments for future developers.
2. `mySet` is immutable, because you initialized it as NSSet which is immutable..
3. `copy`, about that just refer to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397322/does-property-copy-in-combination-with-readonly-make-sense)

Hope this have helped you.

Comment: Why do you say that I'm initialising `mySet` as `NSSet`? I don't see how

Comment: About the copy issue, that discussion doesn't really apply. I'm not asking about `copy` (the attribute) and `readonly` (also an attribute), but rather about `copy` (the attribute) and `copy` (the signal) when used together. I still thank you, though :)